# Unlink não está funcionando dentro de loop

Tags: php, mysql, loop, while

Estou tentando a algum tempo excluir imagens de uma pasta através de um unlink dentro de um `loop`,no caso `while`,porém estou me deparando com o erro:

> PHP Warning:  unlink(admin/imgsupload/32acafa5b1bac0d2af522f76627e3212.jpg ) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in /home/storage/1/05/41/lcjprojetos/public_html/admin/excluirprojeto.php on line 19, referer: http://www.lcjprojetos.com.br/admin/projetos

Pelo o que eu entendi o erro está me dizendo que o diretório ou arquivo não existem.
Porém já chequei e tanto o diretório quanto a imagem existem,tentei dar o caminho completo e sem resultados também.
Segue o código:

```
<?php
include 'seguranca.php';
include 'conexao.php';
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $parteurl = explode('/', $url);

  $id = $parteurl[3];
$teste=mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$id);

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `galeriafotos` WHERE `codigo`=".$teste."";
    $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql2) or die (mysql_error());
    $itens=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2) or die (mysql_error());
unlink("admin/imgsupload/".$itens['imagem']);
$link=$itens['link'];
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `fotos` WHERE `link`='$link'";
$resultado3 = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql3) or die (mysql_error());
$itens2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado3) or die (mysql_error());
while($itens2){
    unlink("admin/imgsupload/".$itens2['imagem']);
}


            $sql = "DELETE FROM `fotos`
                    WHERE `link` ='$link'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
            $sql4 = "DELETE FROM `galeriafotos`
                    WHERE `link` ='$link'";
            $resultado4 = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql4);
            if($resultado4){
                echo "  < <script>window.location.replace('http://www.lcjprojetos.com.br/admin/projetos');</script>";
            }

    ?>
```

Estrutura,esse código está na pasta admin,onde também se encontra a pasta imgsupload:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode ser que o diretório ou arquivo não existe na raiz em que o script de unlink está sendo executado, ou seja, o arquivo PHP acima está no mesmo nível do diretório admin? Se possível mostre a estrutura de diretórios.

Comment: Coloquei a estrutura ali Fábio,o estranho é que o unlink que está fora do while funciona normalmente.

Comment: Não sei se é isso, mas imagino que o problema pode ser o seguinte: O while pode estar passando por um valor null, com isso é retornado para o unlink um valor inexistente. Faz o seguinte, joga o unlink dentro de um bloco if e no bloco else coloca um echo "valor nulo", se for retornada a mensagem então ao invés do erro então saberemos que teu while tá trabalhando com valor nulo. Testa aí, depois dou uma olhada com mais carinho (agora to no celular então fica complicado heheh)

Comment: Fiz isso que você me disse porém não retornou o else,porém o unlink dentro do if não funcionou.

Comment: uma curiosidade o caminho de sua imagem seria esse?

http://www.lcjprojetos.com.br/admin/imgsupload/32acafa5b1bac0d2af522f76627e3212.jpg

Comment: dentro do while imprima as duas variaveis $itens2 e $itens2['imagem'] e veja o que retorna

Comment: Sim esse mesmo thalles,o echo do $itens2 fico = Array e o do $itens2['imagem']=153235afbc0897c23b2fd053b8464df2.jpg

Comment: o caminho quando acessado pela web ta retornando erro tem proteção nesse caminho?

Comment: Quando acessado pela web exibe a imagem normalmente,a parte da proteção eu não entendi muito bem mas se for o que estou pensando a pasta está com permissão 775.

Comment: veja a resposta que coloquei pra ver se te ajuda.

Comment: quando tento acessar pela web sua url me retorna erro de pagina nao encontrada

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30394/discussion-between-thalles-daniel-and-vinicius-zable).

Comment: É a [mesma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92307/91)?

Answer (score 2):

Notei uma coisa muito importante, o seu arquivo `/home/storage/1/05/41/lcjprojetos/public_html/admin/excluirprojeto.php` esta dentro da pasta `admin`, quando você executa `unlink("admin/imgsupload/".$itens2['imagem']);` o caminho é relativo então o `unlink` vai procurar uma pasta chamada `admin` dentro da atual `admin`, o correto seria usar assim:

```
 unlink('imgsupload/'.$itens2['imagem']);
```

Outro detalhe é que até aonde sei o `mysqli_fetch_assoc`  deve ir no laço do loop e não fora dele, pois se não ele só vai pegar o primeiro item.

```
while($itens2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado3)) {
    unlink("imgsupload/".$itens2['imagem']);
}
```

Também pode-se usar `file_exists` pra checar se o arquivo existe:

```
while($itens2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado3)) {
    if (file_exists("imgsupload/".$itens2['imagem'])) {
        unlink("imgsupload/".$itens2['imagem']);
    }
}
```

Se com `file_exists` ainda persistir o erro, você pode usar `clearstatcache`, pois é possível que exista o mesmo arquivo mais de uma vez no seu banco.

Lembre-se que você deve fazer o processe em todos lugares aonde existem `unlink`, assim:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `galeriafotos` WHERE `codigo`=".$teste."";
$resultado2 = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql2) or die (mysql_error());
$itens = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2);

if ($itens && file_exists("imgsupload/".$itens['imagem'])) {
    unlink("imgsupload/" . $itens['imagem']);
}


$link = $itens['link'];
$sql3 = "SELECT * FROM `fotos` WHERE `link`='$link'";

$resultado3 = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql3) or die (mysql_error());

while ($itens2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado3)) {
    clearstatcache();
    if (file_exists("imgsupload/".$itens2['imagem'])) {
        unlink("imgsupload/" . $itens2['imagem']);
    }
}
```

### Conclusão

Fora isto o código possui vários problemas, como em um lugar você usar `while` no outro não, a marcação esta ruim de você mesmo se guiar no que fez e você usou `die()` em alguns lugares que não havia necessidade e me parece que você não sabe muito bem usar `if`, `while`, `for`, `switch` que são conceitos básicos da maioria das linguagens de programação (independente de ser php ou não).

- *Recomendo que leia e estude a documentação:* http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/langref.php

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30437/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-unlink-nao-esta-funcionando-dentro)